# Dynamic Google chart between two dates using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

Here is my code for dynamic google chart:

```
     <?php
        $dateone="20-09-2013";
                $datetwo="15-10-2013";
               $qry1=mysql_query("SELECT count(call_type) FROM tb_name WHERE call_date>='".$dateone." 00:00:00' AND call_date<='".$dateone." 23:59:59'");
               $row1=mysql_fetch_array($qry1);
               $qry2=mysql_query("SELECT count(call_type) FROM tb_name WHERE call_date>='".$datetwo." 00:00:00' AND call_date<='".$datetwo." 23:59:59'");
               $row2=mysql_fetch_array($qry2);

               $chart= array( 
                     array('Date', 'Total Calls' ),  
                     array("$dateone", intval($row1[0])),
                     array("$datetwo", intval($row2[0])));
                $data=json_encode($chart);
        ?>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $data; ?>);

             var options = {'title':'Total Calls'
                          };
            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
```

This code Working fine. But the if i run this code it showing that particular date details one in google chart. I need all counting between that given two dates. How to modify the code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one query. For each date between $dateone and $datetwo you need to count the rows and select the date. You need to group it by the date.

Your MySQL query will be something like this.

```
SELECT count(1), DATE(call_date) FROM tb_name WHERE call_date>='".$dateone." 00:00:00' AND call_date<='".$datetwo." 23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(call_date)
```

Just use a while statement to loop over each row and add it to the chart array..

For example:

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT count(1) as count, DATE(call_date) as Ymd FROM tb_name WHERE call_date>='".$dateone." 00:00:00' AND call_date<='".$datetwo." 23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(call_date)");
$chart= array( 
    array('Date', 'Total Calls' ));
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
    $chart[] = array($row['Ymd'], intval($row['count']));
}
$data=json_encode($chart);
```

But I advise you to use the PDO library for your MySQL connection and queries..

Comment: If i use this query it showing this error:Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Comment: There was a small mistake at the $chart[] line. I've fixed it, does it work now?